# Why Screen is not disappears in Linux as compared to Windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows, terminal, getch

I'm beginner in C programming. When I programmed in Windows using any Compiler then to hold the screen I used `getch()`.

Without it when I run the program, the screen suddenly disappears. But when I did same thing in Linux, there is no need of `getch()`. When I run my program, it runs and screen does not disappear.

Why is the screen (terminal) in Linux is not closed like in Windows?

Comment: Try making your text bigger and bolder - that would make it get answered faster. For even better results - change the text color to red.

Comment: you have any problem to read the text? and if yess, then please edit my Question.

Comment: Or conversely, why is the screen (console) not kept open like in linux?  Not to start a flame but this is mostly a Windows thing. Or visual studio thing.

Comment: If you know the differences then please provide me some links of useful stuffs. I'm eager to know more about Linux.. @ryyker

Comment: It is simply the differences between the two environments.  Keep going, you will find more.  Windows no longer uses a console screen for most of its user interaction (although there is a simulated DOS console, cmd.exe available), where in Linux, many people still use the old vi editor, in a console, with command line abilty.  It just depends on what combinations of tools, environments you are using.

Comment: The best place to learn about Linux is to simply google something like:  ***[Linux tutorial](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/)***, or ***[Linux editors](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/top-5-best-linux-text-editors/)***.  You get the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A console window will be closed by whatever opened it in the first place.

In both Windows and Linux, you can launch a terminal emulator window and specify what program will run in that window. When that program terminates, the window will close (unless you specify some option to keep it open).

Windows software development is typically done from an IDE such as Visual Studio. The usual way to launch a program from Windows opens a terminal window that just executes your program. The window closes when the program finishes -- thus the need for `getch()` or something similar. (Note that the `getch()` function is specific to MS Windows.)

On Unix/Linux systems, you typically launch a terminal window from the desktop manager, and the program running in the window is an interactive shell. If you run a command from the shell, the window remains open when the program finishes; it remains open until the shell terminates (when you type `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> at a shell prompt.

Both methods can be used on either system. On Windows, you can launch a console window running `cmd.exe`, which gives you a `C:\` prompt; you can then run commands from that prompt, and the window will remain open after the command terminates. Conversely, on Unix or Linux, you can launch a window that just runs one command, for example `xterm -e ./my_program &`, and the window will close when the program finishes.

The difference is that Windows, and Windows development environments, place a greater emphasis on GUI (graphical) programs. Support for console programs (programs that write output to `stdout`) is almost an afterthought (though support for such programs is much older). But console programs tend to be easier to write, and beginning programmers are more likely to develop them.

UNIX-like systems, on the other hand, still place a much greater emphasis on programs that write to standard output (though there are also plenty of GUI programs).

Comment: thanks sir.. my doubt almost clear. and now I'm deciding to completely switched from Windows to Linux. @Keith Thompson

Comment: @ranarrjun: switching to Linux is a good decision. However, the good reason to switch is that Linux is [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software): you can, and sometimes you should, study and perhaps improve the source code of the software you are using.

Comment: @ranaarjun -  Another practical consideration to consider is what environment will best support the industry you have an interest in.  Not to start any fires, but my guess is that there are an order of magnitude more development environments, tool sets, you name it for Windows based systems than there are for Linux based systems for ***most*** industries.  (not all)

Comment: @ranaarjun -  The next question you have to answer then, is which one will have a higher likelihood of keeping you gainfully employed.  For the industry I work in, although I love Linux (for speed, simplicity, and cost) Windows is a requirement.  Nobody can use Linux as there are no tools.  So although Windows is a bloated example of an OS, I can make a good living knowing it and using it.

Comment: sir I have interest in System Programming but I see my mates/friends and also my college faculty, they all are interested in Software/Web Development and I see no one who are interested in Assembly and in low level stuffs. and I searched on google and as expected I see Software Development is in more demand as compare to System level Programming related stuffs. If I focus more on System Level Programming as compared to Software/Web Development, then what's my chance of getting good job in Reputed firms/Companies. @ryyker